# Windows 8 - Prevent Transparent Windows when Hovering

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar

Say you have several windows open. Maybe like 4 different Internet Explorer pages with several tabs in each IE window. You know how the icons are grouped on the taskbar, like one icon for similar applications? So if you have 10 IE pages open (counting both windows and tabs in each window) it will group all of these windows as one icon on the taskbar. When you click on this icon on the taskbar it will list all active windows for that grouping that are currently open.

The problem/annoyance that I have is that when you hover over a page for a couple of seconds it will minimize/ghost all windows and display that one window you are hovering over. Technically the other windows sort of go transparent and they don't really minimize. Is there a way to prevent other windows from going transparent.

This wouldn't be all that big of a deal if I was only using one monitor, but the problem is I am running multiple monitors and if I have one specific application running on a particular monitor, I don't want that application going invisible, not even for a second. Since that is the only application on that monitor, I am not worried about accidently loading some other window on that monitor. It is just really irritating when the window goes transparent as I am switching between applications.

Just so nobody suggests this. I already know how to ungroup icons on the taskbar and I have already disabled the taskbar from being on multiple monitors. Of course neither one of these prevent the transparency issue. I would greatly appreciate it if someone lets me know how to prevent the transparency issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is called "Aero Peak", and you can disable it.

In Windows 8:

just hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and write in the search `visual effects` and uncheck Aero Peek

**or**

1. Hit Win+X.
2. Choose *System*.
3. In the left pane, click on the *Advanced system settings* link.
4. On the *Advanced* tab, click on the *Settings* button under *Performance*.
5. On the *Visual Effects" tab, in the *Custom* settings box, find *Enable Peek* (it may be "Enable Aero Peek" on Windows 8.0).
6. Uncheck to disable it, and apply the changes.

[image]

[Image source and more info](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5663-peek-desktop-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: This is great, thank you so much. For me it was just called Enable Peek, running windows 8.1. It works perfectly